A cowboy is dragged by his horse into a diner
I've seen this western movie around 1992. Color, English.
The first scene (maybe while the intro credits are still being displayed), is of a cowboy sleeping on a blank that is tied to a horse. This horse is dragging him over. In one shot, we see the horse go through a road that has a small pond, in which the cowboy's feet gets immersed (but not his head).
Eventually, the horse arrives at the gate of a diner/restaurant. 
The cowboy wakes up and orders a dish of beans and eats it with a piece of bread.
This is all I can remember. 

That's the 1970 Italian Western/comedy movie "Lo chiamavano Trinità.." AKA "They Call me Trinity". That exact same scene happens in the very beginning while the credits are rolling. Here's the scene in question:




This is by far the quickest answer I have ever got on this site. You deserve a medal

@Ahmad - Easy answer since Bud Spencer/Terence Hill movies are a childhood favorite of mine :)
